# jqGrid 4.15.5 locally download no images pagination and css

Tags: plugins, jqgrid

Using the locally downloaded version of jqGrid 4.15.5 the paginator images are not visible and the table colors are gray.

Using version with links http://cdnjs... of jqGrid 4.15.5 the paginator images are visible and the table colors are ok.

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    
            <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.jqgrid.min.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.multiselect.min.css"/>
            
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.multiselect.js"></script-->
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    'use strict';
                    $("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                        colModel: [
                            { 
                                name: 'Code',
                                width: 15
                            },
                            { 
                                name: 'Description',
                                width: 70
                            }
                        ],
                        sortname: 'Code',
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        width: $(window).width() - 50,
                        height: 130,
                        rowNum: 5,
                        rownumbers: true, 
                        pager: "#jqGridPager",
                        viewrecords: true,
                        data: [
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'},
                            {Code: 'Code1', Description: 'Description1'}
                        ],
                        onSelectRow:{
                        }
                    });
                    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
                        stringResult: true,
                        searchOperators: true
                    });
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        $('#jqgrid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', parseInt($(window).width()) - 50);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <table id="jqgrid"></table>
                <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Plugins locally downloaded are:

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.css
jquery.jqgrid.min.js
ui.jqgrid.min.css
ui.multiselect.js
ui.multiselect.min.css
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use the build in browser debugger in order to see if the css files are loaded. Mostly the problem is that there is a wrong url path to these files.  By example in Firefox you can use debugger like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)

Comment: I fixed it by downloading the images locally and inserting them into the CSS root folder. Second step download jquery-ui-1.12.1 redmond themes and apply this to project. Third step add *.map file and jquery.jqgrid.src.js